# Textarea which counting entered symbolys

Tags: javascript, tripadvisor

```js
function someFunc(){
 var integer = document.getElementById('email').value.toString().length;
    var symbolCount = 0 + integer;
    // var last2 = 100 - integer2;

    if (symbolCount >= 100) {
        document.querySelector('.hidden_block').style.color = 'green';
    } 
    else if (symbolCount <= 100) {
      document.querySelector('.hidden_block').style.color = 'black';
      document.querySelector('.error').style.display = "block";
    } 
    else {
        document.getElementById('max').style.color = 'black';
    } 
    
    document.getElementById('symbol_count').innerHTML = symbolCount;
}
email.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
 document.querySelector('.hidden_block').style.display = 'block';
 document.getElementById('max').style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
#max, #max2 {
 text-align: right;
 margin-right: 55px;
}
.hidden_block {
 display: none;
 text-align: right;
 margin-right: 55px;
}
.error {
 display: none;
 color: red;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<label for="email">Positive</label>
<textarea type="email" class="form-control" id="email" oninput="someFunc()"  placeholder="Tell people about your experience: describe the place or activity, recommendations for travelers?"></textarea>
<p id="max">Minimal length - symbols</p>
<div class="hidden_block">
  <span id="count">Symbols : <span id="symbol_count">0 </span> (minimum:100)</span>
</div>
 <span class="error">Your review must be at least 100 characters long. Adding details really helps travelers.</span>
```

Hi everyone.I have a that simple textarea field.I need to realize something like [that](https://www.tripadvisor.com/UserReviewEdit-g187497-d190166-Basilica_of_the_Sagrada_Familia-Barcelona_Catalonia.html).When u write less than 100 words and click the outside of the email id  the border color  must be red.And error class must displayed.And i need to if the textarea field is empty the tag p with id max must be display block if the user will write any symbol the id max must bu display none.Thanks for help

Comment: Use onkeypress event also along with onkeyup

Comment: @Lalit I will check it one minute pls.

Comment: @Lalit thank u event onkeypress is worked great! :) left unsured 2 issues

Comment: No need for multiple key events. Use `oninput` which will cover them as well as cover paste

Comment: @charlietfl thank you .but can u explain why i dont need multiple events ?

Comment: Because input event covers them. Those others don't include paste by mouse for example...input does

Comment: O.o @charlietfl thank you for explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function someFunc(){
 var integer = document.getElementById('email').value.toString().length;
    var symbolCount = 0 + integer;
    var integerValue = document.getElementById('email');
    var hidden_block = document.querySelector('.hidden_block');
    var max = document.getElementById('max');
    var error = document.querySelector('.error');
    var positive = document.getElementById("positive");
    // var last2 = 100 - integer2;
    if (integer >= 1) {
  hidden_block.style.display = 'inline-block';
  max.style.display = 'none';
  integerValue.classList.add("form-control");
 } else {
  hidden_block.style.display = 'none';
  max.style.display = 'block';
  error.style.display = "none";
  positive.style.color = "#002C38";
  integerValue.classList.remove("form-redBorder");
 }
 integerValue.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
  error.style.display = "none";
  positive.style.color = "#002C38";
  integerValue.classList.remove("form-redBorder");
    });
 //Red error and border
 document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  
   if (target !== integerValue && !isChildOf(target, integerValue)) {
     error.style.display = "inline-block";
     integerValue.classList.add("form-redBorder");
     positive.style.color = "red";

   } if (integer >= 100) {
    error.style.display = "none";
    integerValue.classList.remove("form-redBorder");
    positive.style.color = "#002C38";
   }
 }, false);

 function isChildOf(child, parent) {
   if (child.parentNode === parent) {
     return true;
   } else if (child.parentNode === null) {
     return false;
   } else {
     return isChildOf(child.parentNode, parent);
   }
 }
 //Finished Red error and border 
 //Start to count symbols
    if (symbolCount >= 100) {
        hidden_block.style.color = 'green';
        
    } 
    else if (symbolCount <= 100) {
      hidden_block.style.color = 'black';
    } 
    else {
        max.style.color = 'black';
        // document.getElementById('max2').style.color = 'black';
    } 
    
    document.getElementById('symbol_count').innerHTML = symbolCount;
}
```

```css
#email {
 display: block;
 padding: 6px 12px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 90% !important;
 height: 120px !important;
 /*border:1px solid #44A1B7 !important;*/
}
.form-control {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 90% !important;
 height: 120px !important;
 border:1px solid #44A1B7;
}
#positive, #negative {
 padding: 14px 15px 1px 55px;
 color: #002C38;
 font-size: 18px;
} 
.form-redBorder {
 margin: 0 auto;
 border:1px solid #FF0000 !important;
}
#max, #max2 {
 position: absolute;
 right: 1%;
 margin-right: 55px;
}
.hidden_block {
 position: absolute;
 right: 1%;
 display: none;
 text-align: right;
 margin-right: 55px;
}
.error {
 margin-left: 55px;
 display: none;
 color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<form role="form">
   <div class="form-group">
      <p class="help-block">About youre site.</p>
   <label for="email" id="positive">Positive</label>
 <textarea type="email" id="email" oninput="someFunc()" placeholder="Your review must be at least 100 characters long<br> Adding details really helps travelers"></textarea>
<p id="max">(100 character minimum)</p><div class="hidden_block">
 <span id="count">Symbols : <span id="symbol_count">0 </span> (min:100)</span>
 </div>
<span class="error">Your review must be at least 100 characters long.<br> Adding details really helps travelers..</span>
</div>

 </form>
```